# WPML - how to get the permalinks to display also the default language

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, multi-language

Currently WPML adds /fr/ to permalinks to identify a url as French. The default language of the site is English, however WPML does not add /en/ by default for the default lannguage (English) permalinks. Is there a way to have the default language also show up in the permalinks?

Comment: What is WPML? A Markup Language for WordPress?

Comment: WPML is the defacto plugin enabling Multi-lingual WordPress sites, although others exist such as qTranslate. www.wpml.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This feature has been added to the latest version of the plugin.

https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/directory-default-language/

Comment: Could you explain your answer? Meaning did you ask the developers of WPML and that's what they told you...?

Comment: "This is not possible" is rarely an acceptable answer in programming and no information was provided on how to do this with the plugin.